# angularjs google places autocomplete not working locally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-places-api

I want to use **angularjs google places autocomplete** in my local application. 
Code is working when tried in plunker but when same code is copied to local application it is throwing the errors.
[Working code demo here.](http://embed.plnkr.co/IHj6SlyVyxNJEVtzQWUt/)

HTML Code:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    <input type="text" ng-model="search" my-autocomplete>
    <p>Search: {{search}}</p>

    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&amp;sensor=false"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0-rc2" data-semver="1.3.0-rc2" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

script.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
})
.directive('myAutocomplete', function($log) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0]);
      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        var address = element.prop('value')
        ngModel.$setViewValue(address);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Below are the error messages shown when tried in my local application:

```
Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error
_.kb @ js:34
maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/27/12/util.js:210 Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
iB.j @ maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/27/12/util.js:210
maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/27/12/util.js:210 Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required
```

Any suggestions would be helpful to resolve this error.Below is the screenshot of the page when run locally.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The script element that loads the API is missing the required authentication parameter. If you are using the standard Maps JavaScript API, you must use a key parameter with a valid API key. Basically you have to pass the key.Please refer the Api Documentation -
[api link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages)

Comment: Is there a way without generating the key i can make it working, as the demo i showed here: http://embed.plnkr.co/IHj6SlyVyxNJEVtzQWUt/ is working. Is there any other angularjs API to achieve this functionality.